# new with function and its not working

Tags: php, function, fpdf

i am new with functions and don't understand why this is not working:

```
 function NaamKaart ($x, $y, $border, $image, $naam) {

 // zet de border op zijn plek
 $pdf->SetY($y);
 $pdf->SetX($x);
 $pdf->Image("../groepen/groep12/naamkaartjes/borders/".$border.".png");

 // zet het plaatje op zijn plek
 $pdf->SetY($y+2);
 $pdf->SetX($x+2);
 $pdf->Image("../groepen/groep12/naamkaartjes/images/".$image);

 // zet de naam op zijn plek
 $pdf->SetY($y+8.5);
 $pdf->SetX($x+25);

 // zet de font en grootte              
 $pdf->SetTextColor(000,000,000);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',22);
 $pdf->MultiCell(43,7,$naam ,0,'C',false);
 }
```

and i call it like this:

```
 $border = "groen";
 $image = "aap.png";
 $naam = "mijnnaam";

 NaamKaart (20, 10, $border, $image, $naam);
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: Is the `$pdf` variable initialized?

Comment: Yes i have initialized $pdf. When i use it without the function then it works fine, but when i use the function i get a blank page without a error.

Comment: You should really read about variable scopes.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use it without the function then it works fine, but when I use the function I get a blank page without a error.

By default, when you are inside a function you do not have access to the outer variables, like `$pdf`.

> I have initialized $pdf.

I'm not saying this is the recommended way to implement your function, but if you want your function to have access to an outer variable, you have to declare it as `global` inside the function like this:

```
function NaamKaart ($x, $y, $border, $image, $naam) {
    global $pdf;

    // The rest of your code

}
```

Here is information on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thanks this did the job and i shall read about variable scope.